Docker container restart trigger in Zabbix
I want to know the zabbix trigger prototype expression to create a problem if a docker container restarts
last(/Docker by Zabbix agent 2/docker.container_info.state.restarting["{#NAME}"])=1

The above trigger is the one I am using but Zabbix is not creating any alerts
